# How to use AngularJS in Browser's URL bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, browser

I am checking on the possibilities of JavaScript usage in browser's URL bar like the address bar in Chrome and Firefox.

I know that we can write basic JavaScript code in address bar like...
`javascript: {alert(document.getElementById('example')); undefined;}`
This works fine.

But when a page is already loaded is it possible to use all JavaScript code, including the libraries present in the web page? e.g. AngularJS, JQuery?
(Given that they have imported those scripts in their webpage)

I tried `JQuery` and that seems to be working in the address bar but `AngularJS` did not.
e.g. `javascript:alert(angular.element($('.example').children[0])[0].attributes[1])` did not work in address bar. (It does work in Chrome/Firefox JS console though)

So is it even possible to use AngularJS here?
*(I am missing some basic concept here in which kind of code are eligible to be used in address bar of a browser.)*

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do using Js at URL bar?

Comment: @Gabriel, I was expecting this :'D, was fiddling around and got stuck here to know the scope of address bar javascript compatibility :)

Comment: @baao, when you copy paste in the address bar, you will have to retype `javascript:` at the beginning as it is a protection measure incorporated by browsers.. *for XSS attacks i guess*

Comment: Making some tests I came to the conclusion that the URL scope is the same from the console.

Comment: @Gabriel, like already mentioned in the question, I am still not able to use `angular.element...` code in address bar even though the resource is loaded/added in the website.. while I am able to successfully use it in the console..